# AI chatbot with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, machine-learning, chatbot

I would like to develop a chatbot directly inside my Rails app (maybe whatsapp/messenger in the future, but let's begin within my app first).

I've checked online but I find a lot of different ressources and I am not sure which tools I should use.

The chatbot is not for marketing purposes only, it should be able to interact with my controllers and give back some content to the user.
For exemple, I want the user to be able to ask "what is my balance?" or "show me my last transaction" or "how many bills do I have to pay this month?"

In the future I would like to use ML to make the bot "smarter" and make suggestions to the user, but that's not a priority.

What tools and what steps would you recommend to follow in order to achieve this? 
Any gems you recommend? Any tutorial that could help?
Is it possible to do this inside my rails app and using Ruby?

I am ready to try by myself but the content I find on Google is messy and I want to know the best way to do this so I don't lose hours with software that are not really good..

Thanks for your help

Comment: You could use the Whatsapp ruby gem for whatsapp  https://github.com/ignacio-chiazzo/ruby_whatsapp_sdk along with other libraries for AI (openAI! for example)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot configure bot inside your rails app but you can create separate rack for creating bot. [stealth](https://github.com/hellostealth/stealth) is good one.

Read [doc](https://hellostealth.org/docs) for configuring it with rails.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! Why is it not possible to do it inside my app directly? I thought there was some gems I could install

Comment: @Jessicascn I did not use it but I know that it works on MVC logic and have separate in-built functionality, prefer to keep your application logic untouched & provide help as third party. Read document provided, it will give you much better help.